# Allow a page to only load in an iframe

Tags: php, redirect, iframe, permissions, load

How can I allow my PHP file to only load in an `iframe`?

For example:

- Prevent direct access: `example.com/Loader.php`
- Allow iframe access: `<iframe name="TEST" src="Example.com/Loader.php"></iframe>`

Comment: you might be able to do this in js but not with any html/php script

Answer (score 17):

You wouldn't use PHP for that. Try javascript.

```
if(window==window.top) {
    // not in an iframe
}
```

Comment: what about if someone turn off JS in the browser?

Comment: If it's critical that the file only be displayed in an iframe, then block access to it unless you are sure. The only way to know if the page has loaded in an iframe is to check on client-side.

Answer (score 7):

Supposing that you have file `file1.php` that have an `iframe` within and this `iframe` point to `file2.php`

code supposed for the file **file1.php**:

```
<iframe src="file2.php" width="500" height="100"></iframe>
```

content of the file **file2.php**:

```
<?php
echo "This file exist in an iframe";
?>
```

So let update the **file1.php** to the following code :

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['iframe'] = md5(time()."random sentence");
?>
<iframe src="file2.php?internal=<?php echo $_SESSION['iframe'];?>" width="500" height="100"></iframe>
```

and also update the **file2.php** as following :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['iframe']) || !isset($_GET['internal']) || $_SESSION['iframe'] != $_GET['internal'])
    {
        die("This page can be accessed just from within an iframe");
    }
unset($_SESSION['iframe']);
//Continue processing using your own script
?>
```

Try this and tell me if this works or not :)

Comment: This would still allow for the page to be opened outside the iframe. As long as file1.php is not refreshed, you can execute file2.php with the correct internal-variable.

Comment: How may it be opened outside the iframe ?

if the $_GET['internal'] value will not been generated from elsewhere ?

Please can you be more clear in your note or just you are pointing on hijacking sessions ?

Note don't forgot that i am unsetting the $_SESSION['iframe'] variable so i cannot really find how it may be accessed as you say please explain what you mean :)

Comment: If one would copy the URL to file2.php from the source code from file1.php, he/she could paste it in the address bar and the file2.php would open eitherway.

Comment: Ok, missed that. :-) My mistake.

Comment: please can you try coding 2 files by the sample code i mentioned here and try what you are supposing it will give anyone the ability to access the file2 from outside an iframe

Really i cannot find your point of view because as i say that the $_SESSION variable and in the first time the page is accessed within the iframe it will be unset so if you copy the url from the source and put it in the adress bar you would not have privilege because the $_GET variable passed is an old session variable and it is not valid

Please tell me if i am thinking wrong :)

Comment: Like I already said: I didn't notice the unset() statement. It was my mistake. Code should work.

Comment: Ah yes sorry i did not notice your last comment so hope this code will work great :) Please if you find it really usable can you vote it up if you please :)

Answer (score 4):

I know this topic is old, but I was searching for a way to do this myself.

So perhaps others in the future will find this post seeking a pure php method of forcing a page to only load inside an iframe.

My solution is as follows:

If you control both pages (the one calling the iframe and the one loaded inside the iframe) it can be done.

First verify the referring page. If the referring page is not correct, kill the page.

```
$referal_page = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if ($referal_page != $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/main/page/loading/iframe.php') {
    die;
}
```

As anyone can also spoof the HTTP_REFERER this is not an end all solution. So I use a load key that is stored in the database for each user of my site. On the page being iframed:

```
if (isset($_GET['key1'])) {
    $key1 = strip_tags($_GET['key1']);
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT user_key FROM page_keys WHERE username = :username');
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $userkey = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    if ($userkey == $key1) {
        $bytes = random_bytes(12); //random. Increase input for more bytes
        $key2 = bin2hex($bytes);
        $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE page_keys SET user_key=:key WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $stmt->bindParam(':key', $key2);
        $stmt->execute();
    } else {
        die;
    }
} else {
    die;
}
```

On the page that loads the iframe:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT count(id) AS key_check FROM page_keys WHERE username = :username');
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$key_check = $stmt->fetchColumn();
if ($key_check == 0) {
    $bytes = random_bytes(12); //random. Increase input for more bytes
    $userkey = bin2hex($bytes);
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT into page_keys (username, user_key) VALUES (:username, :user_key)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':user_key', $userkey);
    $stmt->execute();
} else {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT user_key FROM page_keys WHERE username = :username');
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $userkey = $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
```

Finally on the iframe itself:

```
<iframe id="page" src="the_page.php?key1=<?php echo $userkey;?>">
```

One could also use header redirects to the page loading the iframe instead of die;

The reason not to do this with javascript, is a user can still disable javascript and load the page causing any php on the page to still be run.

Comment: Being as people are actually liking this answer, I thought I would explain that I created a new solution that is more complex than the other php solution in this post because that solution has a flaw. If a user is determined, they can install a plugin like stopscript, prevent the iframe from loading, grab the iframe src `file2.php?internal=` from the source code, and load the page not in an iframe - as the unset($_SESSION['iframe']); will not have been run yet. With my solution trying that, will cause the page to die and it will not load.

Comment: Bruce, what about if I need to put the whole forum into an iframe and forbid opening it outside that particular iframe? How can I check the condition when the user accesses different pages of the forum inside the iframe?

Comment: create file called framecheck.php. In it put the first two blocks of code I shared. In the forum source code, find the file where the database connection is created. (typically most people call this config.php but it always depends on the coder and the forum software). After the code that makes the database connection add `require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/framecheck.php';`. Add the rest of the code as instructed above on the page that contains the `<iframe>`

Comment: Is there any solution that wouldn't require each user to already have a record in the db? The thing is that I want to show the forum freely to everybody, without the need to register, etc.

Comment: Sure you could set `session_start();` at the top of your forums database config (assuming as session is not already started) and then set `$session = session_id();` Then just change `username`, `:username`, and `$username` to `session`, `:session`, and `$session` throughout my code. You would still need a table `page_keys` with two columns `session` and `user_key`